# Access Token Expires while using Google Oauth 2.0 API after some time

Tags: php, laravel, google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

I started using Google Oauth 2.0 code in order to work on Google calendars for my project.
Everything works perfectly and then suddenly after some time or almost a day the Access Token expires I tried using the refresh token where I'm storing the refresh token in my DB and using the same to get a new access token every time.

It'd be a huge help if someone could help me out with this.
My project is built in PHP ( Laravel ).

[Access Token Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Nkxq.png)

Comment: This is standard OAuth practice. Once an access token expires (usually somewhat at random intervals between 1-24 hours), you use the refresh token to generate a new access token. The endpoint and parameters when using the refresh token are very similar to the ones used when first registering to get the access token, but there are slight differences you need to watch out for (e.g. `grant_type` changes from `authorization_code` to `refresh_token`).

Comment: First retrieval of OAuth access token API documentation - https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#exchange-authorization-code

Comment: Using refresh token to retrieve new access token once old one has expired API documentation - https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#offline

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to follow these steps:

Step 1. If the Access Token fails, use the current Refresh Token to request new Access and Refresh Tokens.

Step 2. Store BOTH the Access and Refresh Tokens that are returned.

Step 3. Use the new Access Token for making Online API calls.

Step 4. When the Access Token fails in 1 hour, go to Step 1.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing my doubts I had a small question 
Would it be fine,
1. To run a cronjob every 30 minutes to refresh the tokens? and store them.
2. To use the refresh token while using the access token every time we want to use the access token to generate a new one

Comment: Yes it will be fine to run a cron job to refresh token

Comment: How about the second scenario about using refresh tokens every time, I want to use the access token to get a new one

Comment: Also whenever I am refreshing token using the older refresh token the new generated refresh token gets replaced with the same older refresh token. is this how it's supposed to work?

Comment: for the second scenario you will not require to use refresh token every time, whenever access_token expire then use refresh_token which will give you both access and refresh token and then replace your both existing tokens with the returned tokens

Comment: Thank you so much, Huzaifa. I was struggling with this for long time

Comment: @groovy_guy I'm glad to know that it solve your problem

Comment: My problem is that the refresh token becomes invalid after some time. How can I get a new refresh token?